# Jira Plan Board: filtering by label hides epics and story points

Tags: jira, scrum, jql, jira-agile

I have a Jira Scrum board and when I use the following JQL query for it, I cannot see the epics or story points in the plan board:

```
Team in ("Team 1", "Team 2") AND labels in (sprint8-candidate) ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

[image: No epics or story points]

but if a remove the label condition, then I can see the epics and story points:

```
Team in ("Team 1", "Team 2") ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

Can anyone explain why filtering by label would hide the epics and story points?

**Update:** as per Barnaby's comment, I can see the Epics if I change the query to include them:

```
(labels in (sprint8-candidate) OR type = Epic)
```

But I still can't see the story points per issue:
[image: No Story Points]

**Update #2**: the story point issue was because someone in my org has set up a second story point field and I was displaying the wrong one in the board Configuration Estimation settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in JIRA epics are just another issue type.

The query that selects based on labels is only going to associate issues to the board that have the label in them. If the epics don't have the label then they will be excluded.

You could add the label to the epics. But I'm not sure if this would be what you want.

It may also be possible to formulate the JQL to include *all* epics, but just the stories that have the label.

Comment: Thanks Barnaby, that works. Any idea why I can't see story points though?

Comment: I've had the same problem with story points disappearing, but never worked out what was causing it. GlennV's answer looks promising though!

Answer (score 0):

Barnaby already explained how to display the epics as well. The fact that you don't see story points is probably because those are not displayed for just any issue type.

I think your screenshot displays features (the ones with the *+* icon) and bugs (the ones with the *o* icon), but by default only epics and stories will display story points. You can associate other issue types with estimates in story points as well. How to do this is [documented here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/configuring-estimation-and-tracking-764478030.html). Look for *Story Points*.

> Estimation will be based on the number of Story Points per issue. This is the most commonly used option.
>   By default, the Story Points field is only available to issues of type 'Story' or 'Epic' (not 'Bugs' etc). If you want to change this, do the following:
>
> 1. Associate the Story Points field with other issue types, see [custom field context](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/configuring-a-custom-field-776636423.html) (JIRA Admin documentation).
> 2. Specify the screens that the Story Points field should be displayed on, see [Defining a screen](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/defining-a-screen-776636475.html) (JIRA Admin documentation).

Comment: Thanks GlennV. Yes, the story points need to be added to other issue types, which mine was. But I was displaying the incorrect of two Story Point fields we have set up in Jira. Just FYI.